# release lock from object in java

Tags: java, notify, thread-synchronization

hello guys this is my code , problem am facing is that despite calling `notifyAll`, it is not releasing the lock , can you please state the reason and tell the solution. Am new to threads. Thanks in advance.

```
class Lock1 {}

class Home1 implements Runnable {
private static int i = 0;

private Lock1 object;
private Thread th;

public Home1(Lock1 ob, String t) {

    object = ob;
    th = new Thread(this);
    th.start();
}

public void run() {
    synchronized (object) {

        while (i != 10) {
            ++i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        try {
            // System.out.println("here");
            object.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("here thread 1");
    }
}
 }

class Home2 implements Runnable {
private static int i = 0;

private Lock1 object;
Thread th;

public Home2(Lock1 ob, String t) {

    object = ob;
    th = new Thread(this);
    th.start();
}

public void run() {
    synchronized (object) {

        while (i != 10) {
            ++i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        try {
            // System.out.println("here");
            object.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.out.println("here thread 2");

    }
}

  }

public class Locking {

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Lock1 ob = new Lock1();

    new Home1(ob, "thread 1");
    new Home2(ob, "thread 2");
    synchronized (ob) {
        ob.notifyAll();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi - could you provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: I don't understand why you have duplicate classes "Home1" an "Home2"? and what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: am just playing with threads and here trying to release all the locks and complete the execution of the program. Here the execution is not completed.

Comment: Works fine when I run it in Netbeans with JDK6.  What were you expecting to happen that didn't happen?

Comment: it is not showing any errors but the execution is not completed.

Comment: It is probably then as Peter Lawrey's answer suggests, a matter of computer speed.  Nothing in your code actually makes sure that the two new threads have started waiting before notifyAll is called.  It notifies no one, carries on, then they wait forever.

Comment: yes sir, it worked after putting some `sleep()` to main thread. Thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use notifyAll, you should also have a state changed and when you use wait, you should check that state change.

In your case it is likely that notifyAll will be called long before the threads really have time to start. (For a computer, starting a thread takes an eternity, like 10,000,000 clock cycles) This means the notifyAll is lost. (It only notifies threads which are actually waiting right at that moment)

Comment: Another great answer; +1, axiomatically.

Comment: sir any way to complete the execution? shall i put some `sleep()` to main thread before the notify is called ?

Comment: A sleep is the simplest option. Another option is for the main thread to wait until the other threads have started, but this is just an example. ;)